# Mantis bugnotes formatting

Tags: mantis

Is it possible to format bugnotes(comments) entered in Mantis bug tracker for an issue ?

I am using Mantis v1.0.8

e.g.

"sample mantis bug notes"

which appears as plain text.

I would like to make it bold  or to display in different color

e.g. similar to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

does any other bug tracking system allow such feature ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Mantis one can use some of HTML tags (unfortunately not all are supported). From my experience (as I remember well) I've successfully used: `<B>`, `<I>`, `<U`>, `<S>` and lists, both ordered `<OL><LI>` and unordered (bullets): `<UL><LI>`. It makes notes and descriptions more readable.

Currently I'm using 1.1.8 version of Mantis but I was successfully using it in older version (prior to 1.0) - so yours should also handle that.

Comment: all allowed tags: http://git.mantisbt.org/?p=mantisbt.git;a=blob;f=config_defaults_inc.php#l1701

Comment: all allowed tags: [github](https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt/blob/master-1.2.x/config_defaults_inc.php) search for: g_html_valid_tags

Answer (score 18):

As it was said by *Gawcio* and *mhu*, the list is limited and in current mantis `1.2.15` use of following tags is allowed in description and other multi-line fields: `<p>`, `<li>`, `<ul>`, `<ol>`, `<br>`, `<pre>`, `<i>`, `<b>`, `<u>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`.

Additionally, following tags are allowed in summary and other single-line fields (e.g. *OS* or *Platform*): `<i>`, `<b>`, `<u>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`. That's funny to have some emphasis in issue summary, right? :)

What is not explicitly said, is that these lists are customizable. Unfortunately, they are so-called global settings, so they can't be set using web interface, but if you have a possibility of tweaking the installed mantis code, you can modify the `<mantis-doc-root>/config_inc.php` file (which is purposed to be modified locally) and add following options there:

```
/**
 * These are the valid html tags for multi-line fields (e.g. description)
 * [...]
 */
$g_html_valid_tags = 'p, li, ul, ol, br, pre, i, b, u, em, strong, code';

/**
 * These are the valid html tags for single line fields (e.g. issue summary).
 * [...]
 */
$g_html_valid_tags_single_line = 'i, b, u, em, strong, code';
```

After server restart, you should be able to use the `<code>` tag in summary and description of your issues.

Unfortunately, mantis tags filters seem to disallow any tag attributes, so it won't be easy to allow free formatting. Personally, I have adjusted its style sheet to tweak the colour in which content of `<pre>` and `<code>` tags is displayed. To achieve it, you can edit the `<mantis-doc-root>`/css/default.css` file and add/adjust following rules:

```
pre         { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #0000CC; }
code        { color: #0000CC; }
em > strong { color: #CC0000; }
```

This way your report may gain some colours :)

Comment: Thanks, I have access to the installed code. +1 for detailed answer to a very old question.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite Mantis (ver.<1.3) default configuration by using your personal `config_inc.php` file under `<mantis-doc-root>/config/config_inc.php`

You can overwrite all default settings in this config file. E.g. `$g_html_valid_tags`, `$g_bug_view_page_fields`, ... Just copy/paste the default values from `<mantis-doc-root>/config_defaults_inc.php` to your `<mantis-doc-root>/config/config_inc.php` file.